# Finding correlation between 2 predictors and a response

Tags: pca, partial-least-squares

I've created a dataset, where the response, y, is related to the predictors X1, X2, by the formula: y = 2X1 + 5X2.

If we look at correlating y with X1, and then y with X2, we get the following:

[image]

[image]

And then if we look at the whole 3D space, we can see that it can all be perfectly modelled by a 2D sheet:

[image]

At some point, when we twist the sheet, we can see how we can look down the very edge of the sheet:

[image]

If I perform PCA and try to find the first 2 principle components of the 3D space (2 x's and y), it would return a set that is looking orthogonality down this sheet, so that it can describe all the variation the best. So this is my question: I don't want to describe the variation, I want to describe the correlation. What technique should I use to return that rotated chart, where we're looking down the edge of the sheet so that we can see that there is some combination that perfectly correlates the predictors with response?

Comment: Realised that I can plot the first principle component vs the third principle component to find this!

Answer (score 0):

Realised the method to do this. Ultimately, I think partial least squares regression would be a better tool, but how to do it in PCA is the following:

We know that the first 2 principle components will be vectors that point along the direction of the sheet. The first principle component should move up the sheet from the origin, assuming that the variation in the described direction is greater than the variation seen when looking down the z (response) direction to see the variation of the 2 predictors (the variation of the 2 predictors should be less, as the response is a multiple, by 2 and 5, of the 2 predictors, and I didn't standardise my data in this case).

So the first PC moves from the origin up the sheet. The second PC moves perpendicularly to the first PC along the sheet to describe the rest of the variation seen (as a result, the second PC will move in a direction where the response measured will remain constant. This is why PCA is a poor tool: we wouldn't know which PC was which, unless we understood the relationship between predictors & responses to begin with, & ultimately, I want to measure how the combination of 2 predictors affect the response).

If we plot the first PC with the 3rd PC - which is a vector that points perpendicularly to the sheet - we can look along the edge of the sheet and plot what I was looking for.